# Make sure images get preloaded on an Ajax Call

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, callback, preload

I have noticed that a jQuery Ajax call don't preload/load the images of the target page before it callbacks. So basically it just loads the html and then make the callback and after the callback it starts to load the image/images.

So my question is if there's a way to make sure that the target page images also gets loaded/preloaded before the append function.

Example Code:

```
$.ajax({
   url: ''+nextHref+'',
   success: function(data) {

   var $response = $(data);
   var oneval = $response.find('#ContainerWrapper').html();

   // Then some kind of function that preloads the target images before it appends the ajax result. So basically the part below is where I don't know what o do.
   $response.find('#ContainerWrapper img').examplepreloadfunction(function(){

      $("#ContainerWrapper").append(oneval);

   });

   }
});
```

Any answers, clues, ideas or experiments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To preload an image:

```
$('<img/>')[0].src = '/path/to/image';
```

or:

```
(new Image()).src = '/path/to/image';
```

You could try this for each image before injecting the HTML you received from the AJAX call into the DOM.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But then I need some kind of callback for that, to make sure all the images have been loaded, right?. So if I add that code into an each function, how do I know when all of them have been loaded?

Comment: Anyone have a solution for this?